# Can I make other developers aware that they can define certain functions for extra-functionality even if they're not required?

Tags: design-patterns, php, object-oriented-design

The language is PHP. I have the certain, in my opinion, code smell, it doesn't feel right: In my controller class that ingests objects of the same type (interface, it's `ViewBlockInterface`), I check if these certain objects have certain methods and based on that, do stuff, if not, just skip that object in the array.

```
if( method_exists( $loaded_module, 'getBlockViewStylesFilePath' ) ) {
    //logic with $loaded_module->getBlockViewStylesFilePath()
}
```

The problem with this approach is that, unless you read the documentation (which, of course, almost no one does), you won't know about it. I don't want to throw errors, but in my interface, `ViewBlockInterface`, I don't want to define these, because **it's not necessary that every block have CSS / scripts attached to it**.

In short, I want the developer to know that if he defines these functions, stuff will happen, but it's not required to have them. I also believe that the scope of this sub-system is so small that I don't want to create 4+ interfaces just for this.

What can I do here?

Comment: what kind of crazy non type safe language is this?

Comment: @Ewan PHP. 5.6 at that. Can't use 7.0.

Comment: Ho will the developers know what methods they **must** implement without reading the documentation?

Comment: @Goyo Well, with an interface, the script just breaks. If they're trying to create an object that's, first, not of the interface I need: it breaks, second, if it doesn't respect the interface, then it breaks again, but here lies the issue: I don't want it to break if they don't implement these **optional** functions, yet I'd still like to let them know that they exist.

Comment: you could use constructor overloading... oh wait

Comment: @coolpasta Writing code that does not work is easy enough. What I don't understand is how do you expect them to make it work without reading the documentation.

Comment: "this sub-system is so small that I don't want to create 4+ interfaces just for this" everything is a trade-off at the end of the day. Can you explain why you feel creating a few interfaces is too "expensive"? You've already done the hard part (coming up with the name; just base that on the name of the method), so its really just 1 file with 4 lines of code that you can write in a minute. For those low costs, you can now `@param ViewBlockInterface|HasStylesPathInterface|HasScriptsPathInterface`, which is everything you need to ensure the rest of the team knows what other options are available.

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer using interfaces to checking `method_exists` like your example. First, the `getBlockViewStylesFilePath` should be defined in a dedicated interface. **Both** the interface and the method should be documented to tell other developers what happen when implementing this interface in their classes.

```
interface HavingStyleInterface {
    /**
     * PHPDoc here
     */
    public function getBlockViewStylesFilePath() {};
}
```

Next, instead of checking the existence of a method, I would prefer to check if an object implements an interface. This check supports type-hinting in IDEs and can be refactored easier.

```
if ($loaded_module instanceof HavingStylesInterface) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Now, you can tell other developers that if he/she implements the `HavingStylesInterface`, something will happen. Obviously, implementing that interface is optional.

Finally, remember the **I** in SOLID principles. Multiple small interfaces are prefered than a big one.

Comment: I believe this is overengineering of my code. I really don't care if an object is, let's say I made them implementing a "loadCssFilePath" by another interface, each small thing will then be bound to an interface that's honestly just useless. I don't care if an object is of the "BlockStyles" interface.

Comment: I didn't say that we should create a new interface for every public method that the class implements. My main point is that checking interface implementation is better (clearer and easier to maintain) than checking the existence of a method by `method_exists`.

Comment: I agree, but that's an issue in my case: I don't want to create these interfaces, as such, I will not be able to do an `instanceof` for these optional methods I'd want others to know about. Makes sense?

Comment: I am sorry, can you tell more about "I will not be able to do an `instanceof` for these optional methods I'd want others to know about"? I miss the point here.

Comment: Sure! The idea here is that, yes, your approach is completely correct, but if I were to check for interfaces, that'd mean that the developers who want to take benefit of me doing that check (to use further logic) would need to `implements N,M,O,X,Y` for each function that's optional. That's extreme in my mind and useless because my system only cares that you're `ViewBlockInterface`, not that you're `HasStylesInterface` or `HasScriptsInterface` or `HasTemplateInterface`.

Comment: I got your point now! Personally, I feel good with implementing multiple interfaces in one class. In fact, if the developer wants to implement the `getBlockViewStylesFilePath` method in their class, by introducing the `HasStylesInterface` you also help him/her to know how to define the method signature correctly.

Comment: @coolpasta "my system only cares that you're `ViewBlockInterface`, not that you're `HasStylesInterface`" Actually, your system does care about that interface, its just an implicit, hidden interface. When you check "does method `DoX` exist", you're checking if the object is implementing a specific (conceptual) "interface", just without using a (technical) `interface`. Having an `interface` to enforce your "interface" makes everything easier - and just costs you 4 lines of code per `interface`; totally worth it in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question originally did not mention PHP (just a code block without language specification), I've tried to come up with a couple of solutions in a few languages I've used:

- Objective-C's version of interfaces, called 'protocols', can have [optional methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW6).
- In Swift, you can define a [protocol extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID277) with empty functions as default implementations for optional methods. They can (but do not have to be) overridden by other developers using the protocol (see [here](https://medium.com/@ant_one/how-to-have-optional-methods-in-protocol-in-pure-swift-without-using-objc-53151cddf4ce#99cd)).
- Java, version 8 and above, allow interfaces to have [default methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/) which, like the Swift case, you should leave empty but might be overridden by other developers.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with construction parameters

Provide a default constructor and overload it so you can optionally pass in more functions. All your objects can have the function, but by default it does nothing

```
class A 
{ 
    function __construct() 
    { 
        $a = func_get_args(); 
        $i = func_num_args(); 
        if (method_exists($this,$f='__construct'.$i)) { 
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$f),$a); 
        } 
    } 

    function __construct1($getBlockViewStylesFilePath) 
    { 
        //set optional function to be what was passed in
    } 

}
```